# GROUP BY Power BI along with FILTER

Tags: sql, filter, group-by, powerbi, measure

I want to GROUP BY the "id" column and then get a COUNT for records that equal "yes".
I want to write a MEASURE in Power BI.

---

This is how my data looks :-

[image]

---

I would want to convert it like :-

[image]

---

Then, I want to just COUNT the number of records that equal "yes", like :-

"yes" has 3 DISTINCT records.
"no" has 4 DISTINCT records.

---

I do know that if I remove duplicates and do some things here and there, I can actually get a COUNT for this... But I need those records for other reasons.

Is there any way I can write a MEASURE to achieve this.

Would really appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Grouped Table = 
SUMMARIZE(
    YourTable,
    YourTable[id],
    "status", MAX(YourTable[status])
)
```

```
Yes = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Grouped Table'),
    'Grouped Table'[status] = "Yes"
)
```

```
No = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Grouped Table'),
    'Grouped Table'[status] = "No"
)
```

Which looks like

[image]

OR: Add another **Count Table** if you like

```
Count Table = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Grouped Table',
    'Grouped Table'[status],
    "count", COUNT('Grouped Table'[status])
)
```

[image]